# React Native Build Failed - javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: Unable to create an instance of com.android.repository.impl.generated.v1.TypeDetails

Tags: java, react-native

I created a new project using: `npx react-native init ShoppingList`
I'm trying to run the project on my physical android device.
But, When I run the project I get this error:

[image]

These are the dependency's versions and variable paths:

[image]

I googled this error but couldn't find anything. Please help.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The same thing happened to me, but I didn't find out what caused the problem. I suspect it was after updating the repository type in the SDK Manager.
The solution for me was to delete package.xml file from the android SDK version folder ("C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platforms\android-28" in my case). The file was recreated when running the project and everything worked as it should. I had to kill the java process to be able to delete the package.xml file.